# Return documents created less than an hour ago - Elasticsearch query

Tags: rest, date, elasticsearch

I need to write a query in ES that only returns documents that have been created less than N minutes, or hours, ago.

There's a `createdTimeStamp` field in millis, and I am able to write a simple query like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "createdTimeStamp": "1526011575731"
    }
  }
}
```

However, this query returns the documents where the `createdTimeStamp` matches the value "1526011575731". Not sure if a range query would work here as the field stores `millis` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `range` together with `now` for that. E.g. to get the last hour:

```
{
    "query": {
        "range" : {
            "createdTimeStamp" : {
                "gte" : "now-1h"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For minutes, use `m` instead of `h`. You can also round, etc., see [Date Math documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#date-math).

That your date is in milliseconds should not make a difference, as internally, all comparisons are handled like that anyway:

> Internally, dates are converted to UTC (if the time-zone is specified) and stored as a long number representing milliseconds-since-the-epoch.
>
> Queries on dates are internally converted to range queries on this long representation, and the result of aggregations and stored fields is converted back to a string depending on the date format that is associated with the field.

(from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html)